# Getting an error when creating the sample (empty) workbook with DocumentFormat.OpenXml (2.10.0)

Tags: openxml-sdk

I want to create a workbook with the data from my program, so I started with an empty one (code below). I tried with and without rows (the code has the rows code commented out), changing the order of a few lines but nothing works.

I took the code from Docs.Microsoft.com / here and http://www.dispatchertimer.com/tutorial/how-to-create-an-excel-file-in-net-using-openxml-part-1-basics/ (the samples are all about the same)

When I try to open the workbook in Excel I get an error: We found a problem with some content in 'Foo.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

I used .NET Core (although I could also repro it with .NET Framework) and DocumentFormat.OpenXml Version: 2.10.0

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Jordi

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("D:\\Diff\\Sample2\\Foo.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook, false))
        {
            // A SpreadsheetDocument must have at least a WorkbookPart and a WorksheetPart
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook(); // Name ambiguity...

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = "Test" };
            sheets.Append(sheet);

            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

            ////Row row = new Row();

            ////row.Append(
            ////    ConstructCell("Id", CellValues.String),
            ////    ConstructCell("Name", CellValues.String),
            ////    ConstructCell("Birth Date", CellValues.String),
            ////    ConstructCell("Salary", CellValues.String));

            ////// Insert the header row to the Sheet Data
            ////sheetData.AppendChild(row);

            ////uint id = 1;
            ////foreach (Spreadsheet spreadsheet in m_sheets.Values)
            ////{
            ////    Debug.Assert(spreadsheet != null);

            ////    spreadsheet.SaveToExcel(workbookPart, sheets, id++);
            ////}

            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

            document.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I did also post an issue in GitHub and I got a response there that pointed to this being a code error not a SDK error. Credit to **Scott Haney** since he replied to me on Github. The summary of the reply is:

It works for me if you remove the line (

> SheetData

is already added to Worksheet when it was passed in as an argument to the constructor so this extra line causes it to be added twice):

```
SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());
```

and also replace

> workbookPart.Workbook.Save()

with

> document.Save()

.